# MSSQL Express: linked server from Access database on network path

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ms-access, linked-server, sql-server-express

I run Microsoft SQL Server Express 64-bit version 14.0.2027.2 (X64) on Windows 10 Pro 10.

I have trouble to set the appropriate network UNC path and other settings for the linked server.

My connection:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'linkedServerName',
@srvproduct=N'Access',
@provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
@datasrc=N'\\unc\to\db.mdb'
GO
```

returns an 7303 Error:

```
    The test connection to the linked server failed.
    An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
    Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "linkedServerName".
    OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "xPohoda_UNC_nopass_Acc" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\unc\to\db.mdb'.
 It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".
 (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
```

What is the workaround to make Linked Server to mdb file specified by UNC path functioning?

Comment: The error message says "It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.". Have you verified if the `.mdb` file is not opened by something else? Have you checked if the user running SQL Server service (you can find out what's the configured user on `services.msc`) has access to the path \\unc\to\?

Comment: Thanks for directing me to right direction:

Comment: .mdb is not opened (but in real life would be opened by another app not-exclusively). The point could be user `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`, which runs MSSQL Server service.
Such a system user is not even "visible" between created users. Should I create such a user (and give him permission to access our SAMBA Unix shares, where .mdb file is located)?

Comment: There's a little catch when using `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` as a service account. Please, check this [Using Local Service Accounts for Running SQL Server Services](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/local-system-account) section to understand it better. But before engaging on that article I suggest an easy test to find out if your problem is actually related to access privileges: if possible, copy that `.mdb` file to the local server runing SQL Server and check if you get the same error message.

Comment: As for an easy test: do you mean to copy `.mdb` file to a local drive and test a connection to my SQL Express? Yes, I did before, and the connection works.

Comment: Yes, that was the test. Now you know your problem is just the privileges of the share and the solution should be grant privileges for the account `YourDomain\YourServerName$` on the share if you wanna keep using `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` as SQL Server service account. Another option would be to create a domain user with the appropriate privileges to run SQL Server service, replace `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` with the new user and grant this new user the privileges to the share.